# How do I Link to my app on iTunes from a website

Tags: app-store

What URL will properly link up my app Twisted 23 on iTunes?

I tried %20 and + subs for the space character, but returns cannot open the AppStore error. I found an answer that said use deep links, but the link was dead. twisted23 was also tried, but to no avail.

Is there a way to format a URL to open up in the AppStore when clicked from an iOS device?

Answer (score 0):

Now it’s working, first from my iPhone and now my iPad. Earlier my cpanel wouldn’t open in Safari, but worked fine in Chrome.

Prolly just cases of incompatible revisions or viruses abounding aplenty. Yay , even The Brave Browser works on my iPhone!

My final comma is practicing social distancing. :-)